# How to make the video blured after seen once?

Tags: css, html, video, blur

On HTML page the video is put, I want to make such kind of task that shows seen videos blur and if we refresh page it will get normal without any overlay i wan to put css or java script for that.

Answer (score 2):

Using JS, add a class to the video once its been watched:

```
.video--watched {
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

I am assuming we are talking about a `<video>` tag.

Comment: This is a nice solution. It should be noted that it doesn't work on Internet Explorer though. Also, in Firefox, it doesn't work until version 35. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: But I did like the answer so +1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean be seen once. Do you mean if the video has ended or if the video has started playing.

JavaScript has methods for detecting whether the video has started or ended.

Here is an example. Let's say you have a list of videos

```
<video id="my-video">
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="video2">
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].onended = function() {
        video.style.opacity = 0.5;
    });
}
```

Alternatively you can add inline event-attributes like so

```
<video id="my-video" onended="blurVideo()">
```